# Differentiation, high school math

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know this platform is for higher-level math. This is just a high school level question but I don't know any more suitable platform to ask. Apologise in advance.

The question is to differentiate the expression and multiply by $x$, do this twice and set $x=1$.
$$\dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$

After differentiating twice, I get:
$$\dfrac{x^{n+1}\cdot\left(n^2x^2+\left(-2n^2-2n+1\right)x+n^2+2n+1\right)-x-1}{\left(x-1\right)^3}$$

I get $\frac{0}{0}$ after setting $x=1$ but the expected answer is $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

Using L'Hospital rule, I get
$\frac{x^n\cdot\left(\left(n^3+3n^2\right)x^2+\left(-2n^3-6n^2-3n+2\right)x+n^3+3n^2+3n+1\right)-2x-1}{3\left(x-1\right)^2}$
which is still 0/0.
Also, this expression is used to calculate a power series, not the other way around.

I'm wholeheartedly grateful for all your conscientious replies, especially Blue and Calvin. I made some calculations error but eventually solved it.

Comment: Thank you, I tried typing in the code but it didn't work.

Comment: You could express this as a power series, but I'm not sure what the intent of the problem is. That is, write it as an infinite sum.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in the given form, the function is not differentiable at $x = 1$. However, either you can take the limit as $x \to 1 $ of what you obtained or you can begin with noting that $\frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x - 1} = \sum_{r = 0}^{n} x^r$ and then differentiate this expression.

Comment: To theREALyumdub, sorry for the lack of clarity, here's more context. The problem is about proving the formula for calculating the sum of squares of the first n positive integers. If I express this as a power series, it would be 1^2+2^2+3^2+... which is what the problem telling me to prove.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to use Lhopital rule to evaluate functions of the form $0/0$? $\quad$ You essentially have to differentiate the numerator and denominator 3 times, which should then give you what you want.

Comment: To Calvin Lin, thank you for your suggestion. Is this the one you are refering to?https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/3d7785840386a94cc10bf59bffa7fe39cc946c43 I got \dfrac{x^n\cdot\left(\left(n^3+3n^2\right)x^2+\left(-2n^3-6n^2-3n+2\right)x+n^3+3n^2+3n+1\right)-2x-1}{3\left(x-1\right)^2} which is still 0/0 after applying the rule.

Comment: @ChemistryLearner: Welcome to Math.SE! ... You'll have to apply L'hopital a total of three(!) times until the expression stops being $0/0$. Together with having to take the original two derivatives, this seems like an awful lot of work to do by hand, but I'm not seeing an obvious way to significantly reduce the tedium. (I'd at least expand the denominator so as to be differentiating a simple polynomial at each step.) ... BTW: In your "after differentiating [and multiplying by $x$] twice" expression, the trailing $-x-1$ should be $-x^2-x$. (You didn't multiply all the way through by that $x$.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, which is a Q & A site for people studying math **at any level**

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thank you, I was intimidated by some topology and vector field questions at first sight. I was afraid that users would expect at least undergraduate education like in some other stack exchange sites. I'm deeply appreciative of how welcoming you all are.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the power series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$.
$$\dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=-(x^{n+1}-1)(1+x+x^2+...)=-(x^{n+1}+x^{n+2}+x^{n+3}+...-1-x-x^2-...-x^n-x^{n+1}-x^{n+2}-x^{n+3}-...)=1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\sum_{k=0}^nx^k$$
The first derivative is $$\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}$$
Multiplying by $x$, we get $$\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k$$
The second derivative is $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^{k-1}$$
Multiplying by $x$, we get $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^k$$
So, on putting $x=1$ we get $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$, as expected.

Comment: Note that the comments that OP made indicate that they are using this problem to show that $ \sum k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$. They have shown that their expression is equivalent to $ \sum k^2$ via what you did, and what they need to do is show that the expression is equivalent to $ n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$.